# Вывод свойств класса через другой класс (dependency injection)

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, классы, php

Как вывести свойства класса Man через метод класса `Work`. Если бы свойства были публик можно было попытаться так `$this->_man->_sex`, но свойства `private`.

```
class Man{
private $_sex;
private $_age;

public function __construct($sex, $age){
    $this->_sex=$sex;
    $this->_age=$age;
}
}

class Work{
private $_vocation;
private $_man;

public function __construct($vocation, Man $man) {
    $this->_vocatione=$vocation;
    $this->_man=$man;
} 
public function showInfo(){
   //echo $this->_vocation.' '.$this->_author->_sex;
}
}

$man=new Man('Мужской',25);
$obj=new Work('Слесарь',$man);
$obj->showInfo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить публичные методы для каждого из свойств класса Man и затем использовать их при выводе информации.

Пример реализации класса Man:

```
class Man{
private $_sex;
private $_age;

public function __construct($sex, $age){
    $this->_sex=$sex;
    $this->_age=$age;
}

public function getSex() {
   return $this->_sex;
}

public function getAge() {
   return $this->_age;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Геттеры и сеттеры норм практика, я так целую ORM построил в своем фреймворке http://jakulov.ru/search/tag/Bun_Framework

Comment: .


    $ok = @chmod($this->path, $mode);
    if(!$ok) {

панян

upd. мой латышский привет вам.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно вместо класса ворк создать интерфейс сменив ворк на профешн к примеру, встроить его в мэн. Тогда для работы внутри класса можно будет обойтись без геттеров и сеттеров.